# Instantiate the parent class in a child class method

Tags: c#, class, object, reflection, instantiation

```
public class Parent {}

public class Child: Parent {
    public Child() {
        Parent instance_of_Parent = INSERTCODEHERE;
    }
}
```

How can I create the desired instance of the parent class in a method of the child class (not necessarily in the constructor, although that's the method I chose for brevity), without referring to "Parent" by name but instead somehow identifying it as the parent of the current class?

Comment: Deleted my answer as appears it did not address the correct interpretation of the question, not clear to me in what circumstance you would inherit from a known class and then need to infer the type on use, can you expand on why you might want to do this?

Comment: @Daniels referring to C1 by name is the Type equivalent of a magic number. Pretend the definition of C2 is thousands of lines long and you run across a random instanciation of C1 somewhere in the middle. Why C1? What relevance does C1 have? Investigation will be required. But if, instead, you see `base` or `parent` or something, most of those questions won't come up, just like using a constant instead of a magic number.

Comment: thanks for answering, I would not make this particular performance trade off myself but understand you have a use case in mind that does indeed need the type inferred at runtime in this manner.

Comment: fortunately my use case is code that runs just once at the beginning of an hours-long process, so performance isn't a major concern.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about performance this will work:

```
public class Child: Parent {
    public Child()
    {
        var baseClass = GetType().BaseType;
        dynamic instance_of_Parent = Activator.CreateInstance(baseClass);
    }
}
```

Comment: performance is nice, but sometimes less important than reusability

Comment: So does this answer your question? Like @Daniels, I would also be interested to know where such a demand arises in real world.

Comment: @Sparr based on votes this is absolutely not what you are looking for... but I don't see what else the question is asking. Could you please clarify why this is not what you are looking for (and ideally why you even trying to do that)?

Comment: I'm not sure if it works, but it's definitely pseudocode-accurate for what I'm trying to accomplish. I haven't had a chance to test it locally. sharplab.io doesn't like it, but that might be a restriction of their environment.

Answer (score 0):

```
GetType().BaseType.GetConstructor(new Type[]{}).Invoke(null);
```

Thank you to DnaJur on the Rimworld Discord for this answer that allows selection of a specific constructor for the parent class to be used for the instantiation.